# function from module calling function , python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

alright, i need to get the function inside more_example_funcs.py to change the page. you can see in the function how i have imported then tried to run the normal code i would inside example_gui.py (actual gui). This is a test script i am using to simplify my problems so i can learn how to fix them.

more_example_funcs.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import example_gui as EG

def get_text(var):
    print var.get()
    return EG.self.controller.show_frame(Page_two) ## this will not run
```

example_gui.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
# import example_funcs as EF
import more_example_funcs as MEF


class start(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        tk.Tk.title(self, "app name")
        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

        for F in (Page_one, Page_two, Page_three):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame(Page_one)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Page_one(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        self.controller = controller
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labels_one()
        self.buttons_one()
        self.entries_one()

    def labels_one(self):
        label1 = Label(self, text="Welcome to page one")
        label1.grid()

    def buttons_one(self):
        button_one = Button(self, text="go to page two", command=lambda:self.controller.show_frame(Page_two))
#        window_one_button = Button(self, text="open popup window", command=lambda:EF.popupmsg("New window 1"))
        text_one_button = Button(self, text="print entered text", command=lambda:MEF.get_text(self.entry_one_var))
        button_one.grid()
#        window_one_button.grid()
        text_one_button.grid()

    def entries_one(self):
        self.entry_one_var=StringVar()
        entry_one = Entry(self, textvariable= self.entry_one_var)
        entry_one.grid()

class Page_two(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        self.controller = controller
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labels_two()
        self.buttons_two()

    def labels_two(self):
        label2 = Label(self, text="Welcome to page two")
        label2.grid()

    def buttons_two(self):
        button_two = Button(self, text="go to page three", command=lambda:self.controller.show_frame(Page_three))
#        window_two_button = Button(self, text="open popup window", command=lambda:EF.popupmsg("New window 2"))
        button_two.grid()
#        window_two_button.grid()

class Page_three(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        self.controller = controller
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labels_three()
        self.buttons_three()

    def labels_three(self):
        label3 = Label(self, text="Welcome to page three")
        label3.grid()

    def buttons_three(self):
        button_three = Button(self, text="go to page one", command=lambda:self.controller.show_frame(Page_one))
#        window_three_button = Button(self, text="open popup window", command=lambda:EF.popupmsg("New window 3"))
        button_three.grid()
#        window_three_button.grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = start()
#    EF.center(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

i have tried to have the function call a new function inside example_gui.py which calls the page to change but i cannot get the import to function right. hoping you guys can help get this working and explain how it worked so i can learn from it.

Comment: ignore stuff i commented out, it was another imported file which did not want to post and confuse things. all above is runable also. when clicking the "print text" button is when page should change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. it is literally the only way i could figure this out...

i have divided my app into 3 pages...

**example_gui_start.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import more_example_funcs as MEF

class start(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        tk.Tk.title(self, "app name")
        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)

        for F in (MEF.EG.Page_one, MEF.EG.Page_two, MEF.EG.Page_three):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame(MEF.EG.Page_one)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = start()
    MEF.EG.MEF.center(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

**more_example_funcs.py**

```
## more_example_funcs.py
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import example_gui as EG
import __main__ as M

def center(toplevel):
    toplevel.update_idletasks()
    w = toplevel.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = toplevel.winfo_screenheight()
    size = tuple(int(_) for _ in toplevel.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
    x = w/2 - size[0]/2
    y = h/2 - size[1]/2
    toplevel.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + (x, y)))

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    popup.title("Information Dialog")
    label = Label(popup, text = msg)
    label.pack(side="top", pady=10)
    button = Button(popup, text = "OK", command = popup.destroy)
    button.pack()
    popup.grab_set()
    center(popup)
    popup.mainloop()


def get_text(self):
    print self.entry_one_var.get()
    M.app.show_frame(EG.Page_two)
```

**example_gui.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import more_example_funcs as MEF

class Page_one(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        self.controller = controller
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labels_one()
        self.buttons_one()
        self.entries_one()

    def labels_one(self):
        label1 = Label(self, text="Welcome to page one")
        label1.grid()

    def buttons_one(self):
        button_one = Button(self, text="go to page two", command=lambda:self.controller.show_frame(Page_two))
        window_one_button = Button(self, text="open popup window", command=lambda:MEF.popupmsg("New window 1"))
        text_one_button = Button(self, text="print entered text", command=lambda:MEF.get_text(self))
        button_one.grid()
        window_one_button.grid()
        text_one_button.grid()

    def entries_one(self):
        self.entry_one_var=StringVar()
        entry_one = Entry(self, textvariable= self.entry_one_var)
        entry_one.grid()

class Page_two(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        self.controller = controller
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labels_two()
        self.buttons_two()

    def labels_two(self):
        label2 = Label(self, text="Welcome to page two")
        label2.grid()

    def buttons_two(self):
        button_two = Button(self, text="go to page three", command=lambda:self.controller.show_frame(Page_three))
        window_two_button = Button(self, text="open popup window", command=lambda:MEF.popupmsg("New window 2"))
        button_two.grid()
        window_two_button.grid()

class Page_three(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        self.controller = controller
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labels_three()
        self.buttons_three()

    def labels_three(self):
        label3 = Label(self, text="Welcome to page three")
        label3.grid()

    def buttons_three(self):
        button_three = Button(self, text="go to page one", command=lambda:self.controller.show_frame(Page_one))
        window_three_button = Button(self, text="open popup window", command=lambda:MEF.popupmsg("New window 3"))
        button_three.grid()
        window_three_button.grid()
```

if you can notice a couple things diff. 1 is i changed command=lambda:MEF.get_text(self), now i can use all my "self." variables in the file (example_gui.py) with my function (get_text) in file (more_example_funcs.py) ... however this was not my issue, just makes things alittle easier and is irrelevant here.

2nd thing that is changed and most importantly, inside file (more_example_funcs.py) i am doing "import **main** as M" instead of "import example_gui_start" ... they are the same file but it does not create a circular import. after hours of reading about this issue, [Python Circular dependencies, unable to link variable to other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740677/python-circular-dependencies-unable-to-link-variable-to-other-file). this was my winner.

example_gui_start.py is the file that i run to use my GUI.
example_gui.py is the file that will have code for GUI looks only.
more_example_funcs.py is the file that i use to put my functions pertaining to buttons/entries etc.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid circular imports at all costs. The best solution would be to make this a method in the class.

```
class Page_one(tk.Frame):
    def buttons_one(self):
        text_one_button = Button(self, text="print entered text", command=self.get_text)
        button_one.grid()

    def get_text(self):
        print self.entry_one_var.get()
        self.controller.show_frame(Page_two)
```

Otherwise you will need to export the function as well as the variable with the lambda call.

Is there a reason you want this function in a separate file?

Comment: this is just an example i use to practice importing an using functions... my actual GUI has 10 more functions that take input from entries etc. trying to have all GUI on 1 page then all the functions on another so its neater... of course this is all helping me learn too.

Comment: your above code throws a syntax ... AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'app' .... also, i really want to learn how to do this with the function inside module not on same file. However, i wouldn't mind making 1 function on the gui file that calls the regular code i use in other buttons. which can be called by function inside the module. but i still end up with same syntax of attribute error

Comment: @ricky6991 Ah, right. I forgot that tkinter is going to block the circular import from completing.

Comment: yes, no matter what i do i keep hitting the attribute error

Comment: If you put something in an answer and then say "nevermind, that won't work", you're creating a very confusing answer. If it won't work, just remove it from the answer.